# How to add a value within Circle Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a imageview which is displayed as a circle by using the code below.

```
ImageView.layer.cornerRadius = ImageView.frame.size.width/2
ImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

how can I implement a label within this which displays a number. I am not sure how to go about doing this. I am quite new to swift therefore I am not if this can be done or if there are better ways about doing this. My goal is to create a custom circle to display within the imageview which displays a number.

Or is it better to embed a view and then use uibeziapath to construct a circle.

Comment: yes, Draw circle using uibeziapath and add label in same custom view.

Comment: You could just add a label as a subview (or add it above your image), match your image's frame and center-justify the text. If your circle is just a solid, you could even use only the label (by setting a background color and a corner radius to its layer)

Comment: @SharadChauhan which custom view? do you mean use the existing way which I have done or created the embeded version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom view using CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath if you want a hollow circle and label inside it. This class does that.

```
class CircleView: UIView {
     let shapeLayer                   = CAShapeLayer()
     var circularPath: UIBezierPath?

    // This is your label, you can its property here like textColor and Font
    let breathingStatusLabel : UILabel = {
        let label           = UILabel()
        label.textColor     = UIColor.white
        label.text          = “1”
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font          = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-UltraLight", size: 31)
        label.alpha         = 1.0
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = frame
         self.setupPaths()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setupPaths() {
        // Add label to your view and set its frame
        self.addSubview(breathingStatusLabel)
        breathingStatusLabel.frame      = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height)
        breathingStatusLabel.center     = CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: self.bounds.height/2)


        circularPath                    = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: self.bounds.height / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        shapeLayer.path                 = circularPath?.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor          = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth            = 6.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor            = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.position             = CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: self.bounds.height / 2)
        shapeLayer.lineCap              = kCALineCapRound
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd            = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.shapeLayer.transform       = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
     }
}
```

To use it :

```
let circle = CircleView(frame: someView.frame) // Some frame is where you want to show this.
view.addSubview(circle)
```

Comment: Could you prehaps breefly explain this code so i can get a better understanding of it. I have tested it and it works howerver for some reason the lable with initial value of 1 does not appear.

Comment: @user9802387 Added few comments.

Comment: If I were to pass a value from another class which contains the value of the label how would I call "label.text  = “newVal" from outside the method.

Comment: Yes, you need to keep a global object and then you can set value like that.

Comment: 1 Last question what does the code "required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }" do.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to create a custom circle to display within the imageview which displays a number.

If you are not using any image in imageView but you just make a circle then its better if you use

```
mylabel.layer.cornerRadius = mylabel.frame.size.width/2
```

and set data as `mylabel.text = "2"` and make sure it is center aligned.